# Content/Excerpt length control for a specific loop?

Tags: loop, the-content, excerpt

Is it possible to control the length of the content or excerpt for a specific query/loop?

I have come across the following code, but this changes the length for all excerpts, I want it focused on a specific custom query.

```
    add_filter('excerpt_length', 'my_excerpt_length');
function my_excerpt_length($length) {
return 20; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://pippinspages.com/tutorials/better-wordpress-post-excerpt-revamped/

Comment: Ah, there it is.  Your article was the one I was actually looking for....  I remembered reading it, but forgot who wrote it.

Comment: Excellent, glad it was helpful.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Answer (score 0):

http://wpengineer.com/1909/manage-multiple-excerpt-lengths/
Does this work for you?

Can apply different excerpts to each time you actually call the_excerpt